# google-maps - how to change bus address when permanently closed message error is shown. Have tried Own the business and suggest an edit multiple times

Tags: street-address

Google Maps search will only show old address of business and lists the company as being permanently closed. Need to edit address but after many attempts at "suggest an edit" no change from Google Maps

Tried suggest an edit and thought this would simply change the address. It did not work.
I also verified that I was the business owner but no success